# Set Value again in mule-app.properties Mulesoft 3.9 CE

Tags: mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

i want to set value in mule-app.properties again. Is there anyway to do this?
Example in mule-app.properties: hostip=192.168.1.116 , in my flow i want to change it become 192.168.1.117

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy. In mule-app.properties you defines properties as you mentioned.

In your flow you use a property placeholder to use the value of that property in a flow or in a configuration. It will be evaluated at deployment time.

Example:

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration"
    host="${host}" .../>

<flow name="someFlow">
    <logger message="host: ${host}" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
```

Comment: How to set value of properties bros ? In your example, i only see how you get value of properties ${host}, can we set  it some how like  ${host}="something"

Comment: There are other ways to configure properties, like https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/properties-configuration-reference#global-property, but all are defined at deployment time. Maybe you are thinking of something like flow variables instead, that can be set during a flow execution https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/mule-message-structure#properties-and-variables?